# Lost SQL Servers but not SQL Databases. Can I reinstall?

Tags: sql-server, disaster-recovery

**My Issue:**
I have two SQL virtual machines that were in an AlwaysOn cluster. All storage for each server was LUN-based. Both servers were accidentally deleted from VMware. But all the SQL databases (including System Databases) are just fine on the NetApp storage environment.

**My Question:**
Can I re-install SQL server on new VMs and use the same systems database from the previous SQL installation? If so, does anyone know of a process for that?

Comment: you can repair system databases,but can't install.so i think this is not possible( i didn't tried though)

Comment: I flagged this to move to https://dba.stackexchange.com/  you may get better responses in that site for core DBA questions

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion :-)